# how to add soap api reference with ssl certificate in console application .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, soap

I'm Beginner to soap API. I have one external soap API. I tried to add service reference .But it shows certificate error. I installed certificate in my local machine. Error is given below

```
    The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Please help me how to add soap API in console application in visual studio...

Answer (score 0):

```
//in .NET 4.0, TLS 1.2 is not supported, but if you have .NET 4.5 (or above) installed on the system
//then you still can opt in for TLS 1.2 even if your application framework doesn't support it.
//The only problem is that SecurityProtocolType in .NET 4.0 doesn't have an entry for TLS1.2,
//so we'd have to use a numerical representation of this enum value:
//ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
//instead of:
// ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

You can look at this page: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1255767/Could-not-create-SSL-TLS-secure-channel

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I tried to add service reference into my project .for that I insert URL that time I got this error

Comment: Can you share your URL? I wanna try it then I will answer

Comment: Sorry!! It can't share.